# Special defrag options to place boot files in special order (for fastest boot)?

Tags: windows, boot, performance, defragment

How can I defrag an HDD of a Windows OS in such a manner that the boot files which Windows loads are placed sequentially each one after another to get the fastest boot time? (incl. drivers etc)

Which options do I need to use in the windows defrag utility? `/?` doesn't show any options that can do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing a normal defragmentation slows down Windows because the Windows boot prefetcher gets broken and has to learn again where the files are stored.

Since Vista, [you can do the following to optimize boot](http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=140262).

- [Install the Windows Performanne toolkit](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4847.install-the-windows-performance-toolkit-wpt.aspx)
- open a cmd.exe [as admin](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/how-do-i-run-an-application-once-with-a-full-administrator-access-token)
- run this command:

  **xbootmgr -trace boot -prepSystem -verboseReadyBoot**

Now Windows reboots your PC several times. After the 2nd pass it defragments the HDD and the other 4 reboots are used to train the prefetcher again.

But this is a workaround. Replaced the HDD with a SSD and all your boot perf issues are gone.

Comment: Sometimes, replacing a hard drive with an SSD is not possible due to costs.

Comment: Yeah my own laptop has an SSD (though my windows suffers, unfortunately, from the long-black-screen-with-visible mouse issue, sometimes without mouse), but the company pc's have only HDD's :P Will try soon and see if it decreases boot time (significantly or not) :) Thank you.